# Division produces unexpected results

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer-division

```
id  client_id   driver_id   city_id status  request_at
1   1   10  1   completed   2023-12-23
2   2   11  1   cancelled_by_driver 2023-12-23
3   3   12  6   completed   2023-12-23
4   4   13  6   cancelled_by_client 2023-12-23
5   1   10  1   completed   2023-12-24
6   2   11  6   completed   2023-12-24
7   3   12  6   completed   2023-12-24
8   2   12  12  completed   2023-12-25
9   3   10  12  completed   2023-12-25
10  4   13  12  cancelled_by_driver 2023-12-25
11  4   13  12  completed   2023-12-26
11  4   13  12  cancelled_by_driver     2023-12-27
```

I have a table above.Then I wrote a code as below:

```
SELECT count(*) as count_total, 
  count(*) filter (where status like 'completed%') as count_completed,
  count(*) filter (where status like 'cancelled%') as count_cancelled,
  request_at as Date
  FROM rides 
 GROUP BY Date
```

I got the table below

```
count_totalcount_completedcount_cancelledDate
4   2   2   2023-12-23
1   1   0   2023-12-26
3   3   0   2023-12-24
1   0   0   2023-12-27
3   2   1   2023-12-25
```

then I wrote the code below

```
with counted_status as (SELECT count(*) as count_total, 
  count(*) filter (where status like 'completed%') as count_completed,
  count(*) filter (where status like 'cancelled%') as count_cancelled,
  request_at as Date
  FROM rides 
 GROUP BY Date)
select Date, round(count_cancelled/count_total*100,2) as Cancellation_rate
from counted_status
where Date >= '2023-12-23' and Date <= '2023-12-25'
```

somehow I got the results like this:

```
DateCancellation_rate
2023-12-23  0.00
2023-12-24  0.00
2023-12-25  0.00
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The result you got in the last is due to `select Date, round(count_cancelled/count_total*100,2) as Cancellation_rate` which has two attributes/ column headers only. If you include `count_completed`and `count_cancelled` also in the select, then those values too will appear in the result. But again, What are you trying to achieve? It is not clear from your post

Comment: An integer divided by an integer results in an integer. Cast one of these two to a decimal

Comment: Optimized percentage calculation: `round((count_cancelled * 100.0) / count_total), 2)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to print the correct Cancellation_rate. But you have to change the type of a variable to float for it to work.

```
select Date, round(((count_cancelled * 1.0)/count_total)*100, 2) as Cancellation_rate
from counted_status where Date >= '2023-12-23' and Date <= '2023-12-25'
```

Replace the last statement with this.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of change the valuable type. I change it to numeric and then it works. 

select Date, round(((count_cancelled::NUMERIC * 1.0)/count_total::NUMERIC)*100, 2) as Cancellation_rate
from counted_status where Date >= '2023-12-23' and Date <= '2023-12-25'

Comment: then you should mark @Ajax 's answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

```
with counted_status as (SELECT count(*) as count_total, 
  count(*) filter (where status like 'completed%') as count_completed,
  count(*) filter (where status like 'cancelled%') as count_cancelled,
  request_at as Date
  FROM rides 
JOIN users
  on users.user_id = rides.client_id
  where users.banned = 'No'  
 GROUP BY Date)
select Date, round((count_cancelled::NUMERIC /count_total::NUMERIC)*100, 2) as Cancellation_rate
from counted_status where Date >= '2023-12-23' and Date <= '2023-12-25'
```

thanks Frank Heikens and Ajex for remind to change the variable type. I add ::numeric and it works.